# Access the page size in a Material UI `<DataGrid autoPageSize/>`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

By using `<DataGrid autoPageSize/>`, as described [in the docs](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/pagination/#auto-size), you can get a Material UI table that automatically sets the page size (ie the number of rows per page) based on the browser height. However, if you are progressively loading data from the server, you need to know what that page size is, in order to know how much data to load per page, and which row the table is up to. As far as I can tell, the `DataGrid` only gives you access to the *page number* (through various events) which doesn't let you determine the page *size*.

The component does give you access to a [`pageSizeChange`](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/events/#catalog-of-events) event, but this doesn't actually fire when the component automatically sets its page size using `autoPageSize`, so it doesn't help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also ran into the same issue of trying to use DataGrid with server-side pagination. After some digging around, I found that I'm able to see that `onPageSizeChange` is triggered when the component first loads. See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/datagriddemo-material-demo-forked-xqw08?file=/demo.tsx).

If you look at the console after refreshing the codesandbox browser, it prints 0, then 5. You could save this into state and then use it in your `onPageChange` calls.

Comment: Seems like not working anymore..
Property 'onPageSizeChange' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'...

Answer (score 1):

## 2023 update - MUI X 6.18.4

**UPDATE**: the accepted answer is a bit older and the `onPageSizeChange` is indeed not available anymore I found out that you can get the calculated page size through the  `onPaginationModelChange`.

you also get this information through the `onStateChange` but you will have to dig a bit to find it. (It's located in `pagination.paginationModel.pageSize`).

Comment: This is very helpful. Was getting the same issue, now i see that i had this update